# Google script triggers 2 times on each day on weekdays

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I've a google script that I want to trigger at this specific criteria:

1. Weekdays: Monday-Friday (5 times a week)
2. At around 7.45am and 5.15pm (2 times a day)

I don't know whether this code gonna work:

```
function Triggers() {

  var days = [
    ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY,
    ScriptApp.WeekDay.TUESDAY,
    ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY,
    ScriptApp.WeekDay.THURSDAY,                                            
    ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY
  ];

  for (var i=0; i<days.length; i++) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("auto_data_entry")
    .timeBased()
    .onWeekDay(days[i])
    .atHour(8)
    .inTimezone("Asia/Jakarta")
    .create();
  }
}
```

Does anyone have another way to trigger the script and run this programmatically?

I also wonder, if there is a holiday on a weekday, I don't want the script to be triggered.
Is there a way I could skip/cancel/pause a day the trigger if another trigger is triggered, and continue it on the next weekday..

Thanks!

Comment: Try it and see if  it works.   If it doesn't debug it and return with the details of your debugging to help us determine what's not working.

Comment: Make a test project where the triggered function only prints the current datetime. This way you will be able to see when they are called without side effects. If you have problems, then ask :)